# Linux Mint Unable to fomat disk

Tags: linux, installation, linux-mint

- While installing Mint it showed same problem that disk formatting error or unable to find disk.
  But while changing it to Klai linux it installed without issue.

Help me analyze the issue and solve it in a proper manner?

Comment: What does your BIOS tell you about the disks?

Answer (score 1):

This may be an issue with the actual linux mint iso or your computer cannot read the contents of the linux mint iso, you may also be installing an old version of linux mint. I think one of these factors are causing your computer to give this error message, try checking the version of the iso and where you actually got the iso.